# Changing endianness of hexadecimal char array

Tags: c++, string, hex, endianness

I'm using a code snippet like the following (from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723403/char-array-to-hex-string-c)):

```
char const hex_chars[16] = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };

for( int i = data; i < data_length; ++i )
{
  char const byte = data[i];

  string += hex_chars[ ( byte & 0xF0 ) >> 4 ];
  string += hex_chars[ ( byte & 0x0F ) >> 0 ];
}
```

It works; however, it produces a string like `F0000000` (for example).

Firstly, what endianness is this?

Secondly, how could I change the code to change the endianness of the output?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I should've included this. `string` is a `std::string`, `data` is an array of `char`s and `data_length == 4`.

Comment: It's not any endianness. Endianness is not applicable to the code you posted.