# Format signed char or unsigned char with stringstream

Tags: c++, format, iostream, stringstream

The Following code does not work as expected:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::int8_t(-1);
    std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
}
```

What I want is to convert a signed char to a fixed length hex representation. The output is always 0�.

Converting to unsigned int also print unexpected output:

```
ss << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << std::setw(2) << (unsigned int)std::int8_t(-1);
```

This will print ffffffff which is correct but I told the stream to set the width to 2. Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: If you want the hex value of a `char` or `unsigned char`, please, convert it to `int` or `unsigned`. The overloaded stream output operators for `char` and `unsigned char` are intended to write characters (but not their integral values). To fix your latter issue, a two step conversion will help: `(unsigned)(unsigned char)std::int8_t(-1)`. Otherwise, you get a sign extension - hence the 8 `f`s (representing the bit pattern of a 32 bit -1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cast the `-1` to `uint8_t` to get `255`, casted to `unsigned int` will stay at `255`, which then gets printed as `ff`:

```
ss << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << std::setw(2) << (unsigned int)std::uint8_t(-1);
```

When you cast it to `int8_t`, it will stay at `-1`, casted to `unsigned int` will give you `4294967295`, which then will be printed as `ffffffff`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast to unsigned char first, to get the value in range 0-255:

```
ss << std::setfill('0') << std::hex << std::setw(2) << (int)std::uint8_t(-1);
```

Then it is cast to any integral type bigger than `char` (here `int`) to make it print as number and not character.